# how to change the active-state background-color of buttons in Angular-Material?

Tags: angular-material

The title nearly asks all:
1. How can I change the color when the button was **clicked** ?
1. How can I change the color when the button is **hovered**?

Angular-Material already provides a hover- and active-effect (with the same color and opacity); but I havn't found the place where I can change the default settings . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update latest version of angular material(0.9.0) they fixed to overwrite custom css files. For button classes `.md-button` and you'll code and change the code like simple css